# Extracting Spectogram of every Audio file

Tags: python, audio, spectrogram, librosa

I am doing my final year project of genre classification. For that I need to extract spectogram of multiple files. I know how to extract 
 the spectogram of single audio, but i need spectogram for every audio file.

My for loop code is:

```
#display Spectrogram
for file in range(0,len(audio_path),1):

    X = librosa.stft(x)
    Xdb = librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
    librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='hz') 
    #If to pring log of frequencies  
    #librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
    plt.colorbar()
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55487391/unable-to-use-multithread-for-librosa-melspectrogram/55680757#55680757) has example code on how to do this, including using multiple CPU cores to speed it up.