# Is it possible to use multithread to extract audio features (librosa, opensmile and essentia)?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, audio, librosa, audeering-opensmile

I'm working with the libraries librosa, opensmile and essentia to extract features from the audio, however, despite being able to, the process is extremely time consuming and making it impossible for me to continue with my project.

Basically I have 4303 wav files with 30 seconds each. As an environment, I have been using the free version of Colab. I know that it is possible to use gpu in this environment or to develop some kind of Multithreading, however, I still don't have much experience in these matters.

Therefore, I would like to know if there is any way to optimize my solution, considering that the current solution goes beyond 12 hours of processing and does not finish, because the environment falls.

The code used is below:

```
!pip install opensmile
!pip install sox
!pip install essentia
!pip install librosa
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import opensmile
import essentia
import essentia.standard as es
import librosa
```

```
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/vocal' 

files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort(key=lambda f: int(re.sub('\D', '', f))
```

```
voiceFeatures = []

for f in files:

  smile = opensmile.Smile(
    feature_set=opensmile.FeatureSet.eGeMAPSv02
  )
  y = smile.process_file(path+'/'+f)

  audio = es.MonoLoader(filename= path+'/'+f)()
  
  run_gfcc = es.GFCC(numberCoefficients=12)
  gfccs = run_gfcc(audio)

  y_, sr = librosa.load(path+'/'+f)
  
  f1Mean     =  y.F1frequency_sma3nz_amean 
  f1STD      =  y.F1frequency_sma3nz_stddevNorm
  f1BandMean =  y.F1bandwidth_sma3nz_amean
  f1BandSTD  =  y.F1bandwidth_sma3nz_stddevNorm
  f2Mean     =  y.F2frequency_sma3nz_amean  
  f2STD      =  y.F2frequency_sma3nz_stddevNorm
  f2BandMean =  y.F2bandwidth_sma3nz_amean
  f2BandSTD  =  y.F2bandwidth_sma3nz_stddevNorm
  f3Mean     =  y.F3frequency_sma3nz_amean 
  f3STD      =  y.F3frequency_sma3nz_stddevNorm
  f3BandMean =  y.F3bandwidth_sma3nz_amean
  f3BandSTD  =  y.F3bandwidth_sma3nz_stddevNorm
  voicedMean =  y.MeanVoicedSegmentLengthSec
  voicedSTD  =  y.StddevVoicedSegmentLengthSec
  unvoicedMean = y.MeanUnvoicedSegmentLength
  unvoicedSTD  = y.StddevUnvoicedSegmentLength
  f0Mean =       y['F0semitoneFrom27.5Hz_sma3nz_amean']
  f0STD  =       y['F0semitoneFrom27.5Hz_sma3nz_stddevNorm']
  hnrMean =      y.HNRdBACF_sma3nz_amean
  hnrSTD =       y.HNRdBACF_sma3nz_stddevNorm
  jitterMean =   y.jitterLocal_sma3nz_amean
  jitterSTD =    y.jitterLocal_sma3nz_stddevNorm
  shitterMean =  y.shimmerLocaldB_sma3nz_amean
  shitterSTD =   y.shimmerLocaldB_sma3nz_stddevNorm
  gfccsMean  =    np.mean(gfccs[1])
  gfccsSTD   =    np.std(gfccs[1])
  mfcc      =     librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y_, sr=sr, n_mfcc=16) # mfcc - 16

  features ={
      "title":        f,
      "f1Mean":       f1Mean[0],
      "f1STD":        f1STD[0],
      "f1BandMean":   f1BandMean[0],
      "f1BandSTD":    f1BandSTD[0],
      "f2Mean":       f2Mean[0], 
      "f2STD":        f2STD[0],
      "f2BandMean":   f2BandMean[0],
      "f2BandSTD":    f2BandSTD[0],
      "f3Mean":       f3Mean[0],
      "f3STD":        f3STD[0],
      "f3BandMean":   f3BandMean[0],
      "f3BandSTD":    f3BandSTD[0],
      "voicedMean":   voicedMean[0], 
      "voiceSTD":     voicedSTD[0],
      "unvoicedMean": unvoicedMean[0],
      "unvoicedSTD":  unvoicedSTD[0],
      "f0Mean":       f0Mean[0],
      "f0STD":        f0STD[0],
      "hnrMean":      hnrMean[0],
      "hnrSTD":       hnrSTD[0],
      "jitterMean":   jitterMean[0],
      "jitterSTD":    jitterSTD[0],
      "shitterMean":  shitterMean[0], 
      "shitterSTD":   shitterSTD[0],
      "gfccsMean":    gfccsMean,
      "gfccsSTD":     gfccsSTD,
      "mfcc1Mean":    np.mean(mfcc[0]),
      "mfcc1STD":     np.std(mfcc[0]),
      "mfcc2Mean":    np.mean(mfcc[1]),
      "mfcc2STD":     np.std(mfcc[1]),
      "mfcc3Mean":    np.mean(mfcc[2]),
      "mfcc3STD":     np.std(mfcc[2]),
      "mfcc4Mean":    np.mean(mfcc[3]),
      "mfcc4STD":     np.std(mfcc[3]),
      "mfcc5Mean":    np.mean(mfcc[4]),
      "mfcc5STD":     np.std(mfcc[4]),
      "mfcc6Mean":    np.mean(mfcc[5]),
      "mfcc6STD":     np.std(mfcc[5]),
      "mfcc7Mean":    np.mean(mfcc[6]),
      "mfcc7STD":     np.std(mfcc[6]),
      "mfcc8Mean":    np.mean(mfcc[7]),
      "mfcc8STD":     np.std(mfcc[7]),
      "mfcc9Mean":    np.mean(mfcc[8]),
      "mfcc9STD":     np.std(mfcc[8]),
      "mfcc10Mean":   np.mean(mfcc[9]),
      "mfcc10STD":    np.std(mfcc[9]),
      "mfcc11Mean":   np.mean(mfcc[10]),
      "mfcc11STD":    np.std(mfcc[10]),
      "mfcc12Mean":   np.mean(mfcc[11]),
      "mfcc12STD":    np.std(mfcc[11]),
      "mfcc13Mean":   np.mean(mfcc[12]),
      "mfcc13STD":    np.std(mfcc[12]),
      "mfcc14Mean":   np.mean(mfcc[13]),
      "mfcc14STD":    np.std(mfcc[13]),
      "mfcc15Mean":   np.mean(mfcc[14]),
      "mfcc15STD":    np.std(mfcc[14]),
      "mfcc16Mean":   np.mean(mfcc[15]),
      "mfcc16STD":    np.std(mfcc[15]),
  }

  voiceFeatures.append(features)
  df  = pd.json_normalize(voiceFeatures)
```

Comment: `sr=22500`. That's quite an odd choice, never seen that before. Did you intend `22050` ? Still unusual, but al least that's 44.1 kHz/2 (half the CD sample rate).

Comment: In general, resampling takes a lot of time, and it appears that you might resample each file three times. Is that necessary?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Indeed, there is a misconception (22050 is correct). Furthermore, the files have these parameters: wav; 22050 Hz, 1 channel, s16, 360 kbps. I don't have a lot of experience with this kind of processing, so I don't know if something in my code is pushing up the processing time. Do you have any suggestions that could help me?

Comment: Here is an example of multiprocessing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680757/1967571

Answer (score -1):

For extracting audio features from a large amount of data, here is a detailed performance comparison of several libraries: audioFlux, torchaudio, librosa, and essentia.

https://github.com/libAudioFlux/audioFlux/issues/22

[This is audioflux/librosa/essentia performance comparison chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYVXk.png)

Among them, audioflux and torchaudio are much faster than librosa and essentia, and torchaudio also supports GPU. However, compared to audioflux, torchaudio has a much smaller number of features.

The specific choice depends on the business situation, so it's important to do more testing.

I'm new to this area too, I hope the above answers are helpful to you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).